# How do I fix this glitch?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

The glitch is as following:

- I was fighting against a minor settlement and when I was about to win, a pop-up appeared, asking me if I wanted to Continue the battle (to run down the remaining few troops) or to just end the fight.
- I wanted to finish them off. So I clicked continue. However, even after I have wiped them out, the game did not end. I thought that I had missed out an enemy soldier or two but after 20 minutes of scouting the map, I found nothing.
- Therefore, I had to wait the full 60 minutes of the battle's time limit and after that, the game told me that I had lost the battle as I failed to win the battle within the given time.

Thus, I would like to know a few things:

**How can I prevent this from happening again? Can I end the battle after I clicked continue on the pop-up and still win the battle? What exactly caused this glitch?**

Comment: Sorry that I could not explain it properly. It is hard to put the glitch in words. For those who would like me to clarify please ask.

Comment: What you described sounds like a bug in the game to me.

Comment: @DavidToh Report it to Rome 2 Total War's Support Forum on Steam and in a Support Ticket on their official dev site. I Agree with Aaron that it sounds like a bug in a function that was never completed.

Comment: If you were attacking a settlement, shouldn't you have been able to occupy the central square for the minute or two required?

Answer (score 1):

This  might be a bug or not but you could stop at any time you wanted. When you clicked continue you can kill any remaining soldiers but it should end  aytomatically when no enemy soldiers remain. The way to exit this when you want is just clicking escape and then click end battle(only if you had clicked continue). I have done this in my playthrough and it took it as a win.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some units were hidden but not routed, in which case, for an attack, you might not win the battle?

I have seen it take a long time for a slow armoured infantry unit (single remaining man) to flee from one corner of the map to the other, but a whole 50 odd minutes seems a bit much!

Sounds awful anyway, like it doesn't already take long enought to get anywhere in this game!

Oh, BTW, if you end at the first opportunity the AI judges (admittedly not very well) what your units would have continued to do to the fleeing enemy - so no need to worry about not getting those extra spam kills!